# Converting a single line string to integer array in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to learn python through HackerRank, and I've been stuck on reading stdin.  The problem gives an array of integers as a single line of text formatted like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

This should become the array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].
```

Since there are spaces in between the numerals in the input, how can I get to an array?  I've tried split() and map(), but I kept getting errors or an array that still had spaces.

Thank you!

Comment: I apologize if this is too basic -- I've spent an hour on this and I'm stuck...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the downvote doesn't come from the "basic"-ness of the question but of not showing some effort with what you've done. Some code? Why `split` doesn't work? What made you think that `map` would work? A particular error you're getting? That kind of stuff...

Comment: `list(map(int, "1 2 3 4 5".split()))`

Comment: @BorrajaX I'll be sure to do that in the future -- thank you for your help

Comment: @BorrajaX  Got it!  it made me wait a few minutes before choosing a best answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
list(map(int, "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ")))
```

Comment: >>> map(int, "1 2 3 4 5".split(" "))
<map object at 0x7f4b2489bc90>

Answer (score 10):

This list comprehension works equally well on Python2 and Python3

```
[int(x) for x in "1 2 3 4 5".split()]
```

`str.split()` when given no parameters will split on any whitespace